# Why does Node.js shows that a variable is not a function only while using it and not before?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to javascript and I am trying to use [this filter](https://github.com/mljs/savitzky-golay).

However, it shows me an error saying `savitzskyGolay is not a function`. But when I print the said constant, it shows `"{default: [Function : savitzskyGolay]}."`

I saw something about circular dependencies. But I am using only one module.

```
let data = [4,6,78,3,86,0,45,18,27,54,72,81,94,0,10,29,33,46,58,62,100,50,23,76]
console.log(data)

// Filtering Data
const savitzkyGolay = require('ml-savitzky-golay');
console.log(savitzkyGolay);
let options = { derivative: 0 };
let ans = savitzkyGolay(data, 1, options);
console.log(ans); // smoothed data
```

Comment: Try using `savitzkyGolay.default` instead. It seems it's a object with one key `default` which is a function.

Comment: "*But when I print the said constant, it shows "{default: [Function : savitzskyGolay]}.*" yes, which shows you that it's an *object* which has a property called `default` and that property has a function assigned to it. An object is not a function.

Comment: Try changing the import to `const { default: savitzkyGolay } = require('ml-savitzky-golay');`